# Client server application for file transfer

Tags: c, multithreading, file, server

I have an application for transferring files from clients to a server. A client opens, transfers a file to the server and closes. The server is open and may receive multiple files. Also, when transferring a file, a loader bar is created on both server (the server must have some way to display multiple loaders simultaneously) and client. Also, every file transfer is handled in a separate thread on server. 
This is a structure that will be used in server function:

```
struct fileWriteArgs{
    int childNumber;
    int sockfd;
};
```

**Here is the server function** (the main function just parses arguments and calls this):

```
int serverFileTransfer(int port, char* filename){

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd<0)
        errorOpeningSocket();

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    memset((char*) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        errorOnBinding();

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    socklen_t cilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    pthread_t newThread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    int noOfChilds = 0;

    while(1){
        int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &cilen);
        noOfChilds++;

        struct fileWriteArgs args;
        args.sockfd = newsockfd;
        args.childNumber = noOfChilds;

        if(newsockfd < 0)
            errorOnAccept();

        pthread_create(&newThread, &attr, &fileWrite, &args);

    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, it opens a socket and creates threads for file accept (note that I am using a Linux operating system). Also, it calls some error functions that I think are pretty explicit (they just write a message and call `exit()`).

**Here are the `loader` and `fileWrite` functions:**

```
void loader(int val, int max, int size, int row){

    static int lastPrinted = 0;

    int percent = (100.*val)/max;
    int count = ((float)percent * size) / 100;

    if(count == lastPrinted)
        return;

    if(row > 0){
        printf("\033[s"); //save current position
        printf("\033[%dB\n", row);
    }

    lastPrinted = count;
    printf("\r[");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("#");
    for(; i < size; i++)
        printf(".");

    printf("] %d%%", percent);
    if(row > 0)
        printf("\033[u");
    fflush(stdout);
}

static pthread_mutex_t STDOUT_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* fileWrite(void *fd){

    struct fileWriteArgs *p = (struct fileWriteArgs*)fd;
    int sockfd = p->sockfd;
    int childNumber = p->childNumber;

    char sz[32];
    read(sockfd, sz, 32);
    int fileSize = atoi(sz);

    char fileNameSize;
    int readed = read(sockfd, &fileNameSize, 1);
    if(readed < 0)
        errorReadingFromSocket();
    else if(fileNameSize == 0)
        errorBadFileName();

    char filename[256];
    readed = read(sockfd, filename, fileNameSize);
    if(readed < 0)
        errorReadingFromSocket();

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if(f == NULL){
        errorOpeningFile();
    }

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n = 0;
    while(n < fileSize){
        readed = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if(readed < 0)
            errorReadingFromSocket();

        write(fileno(f), buffer, readed);

        n += readed;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&STDOUT_mutex);
        loader(n, fileSize, LOADER_LENGTH, childNumber);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&STDOUT_mutex);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return NULL;

}
```

**This is the client function:**

```
int clientFileTransfer(char *ip, int port, char* filename){

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
        errorOpeningSocket();

    struct hostent* server = gethostbyname(ip);
    if(server == NULL)
        noServerFound();

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset((char*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    bcopy((char*) server -> h_addr, (char*) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server -> h_length);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        errorConnecting();

    fileRead(filename, sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**And the `fileRead` function:**

```
void fileRead(char *filename, int sockfd){

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if(f == NULL){
        errorOpeningFile();
        return;
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileSize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char size[32];
    sprintf(size, "%d", fileSize);
    write(sockfd, size, 32);

    char *name = strrchr(filename, '/');
    if(name == NULL)
        name = filename;
    else
        name++;

    char fileNameSize = strlen(name)+1;
    write(sockfd, &fileNameSize, 1);  //WARNING! it works only for files
                                           //with at most 255 characters

    write(sockfd, name, strlen(name)+1);

    int n = 0; //total bytes read/written
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while(!feof(f)){
        int read = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f);
        if(read < 0)
            errorReadingFromFile();

        write(sockfd, buffer, read);

        n+=read;
        loader(n, fileSize, LOADER_LENGTH, 0);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

The `clientFileTransfer` and `fileRead` functions are used by the client in a similar manner to `serverFileTransfer` and `fileWrite`, that are used by server.

As the code is pretty large, I would like some parts to be reviewed especially, as I feel there is something wrong there. My primary concern is the loader function. It has a static variable that keeps the value that was written last time when the function was called (to avoid printing the same thing all over again). I do not know if this is a good thing. Also this is my first multithreaded application, so I would like some remarks about the way that multithreading is implemented here.

Of course, I would really appreciate if I get also a review of the other parts of this application and remarks about it (what I have done right and where something is wrong).

Comment: I know that and I specified the parts that I am interested in, but I tought it will be nice if I show the whole thing, maybe I will get a superficial remark at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice code in general.  Many of my comments are a bit on the
nit-picking level, so apologies in advance.

Your method of error handling seems to be just to exit, so the return
values from various functions should probably be `void`.  This method
of error handling is certainly easy but might be considered lazy :-) I
notice that you don't check for EINTR in any failed socket calls -
should it not be handled?

Some of the variable names are too long for my taste.  `newsockfd`
for example in the `accept` loop could be just `fd` with no loss.

---

In `fileRead` and `fileWrite`

These functions seem misnamed.  Clearly one does read a file and one
writes but I think names containing 'send' and 'receive' would be
clearer.  Having `clientFileTransfer` 'connect' to the server socket
and then do a `fileRead` implies to me that it is receiving a file
when in fact it is sending!

Some details I noticed are that `fileNameSize` should be unsigned if
you want to handle names up to 255 chars long.  And it would be better
to reject files with names longer than 255 instead of just adding a
warning comment.

```
unsigned char fileNameSize = strlen(name)+1;
write(sockfd, &fileNameSize, 1);  //WARNING! it works only for files
                                  //with at most 255 characters

write(sockfd, name, strlen(name)+1);
```

In the `fileRead` code above you could re-use `fileNameSize` in the
last `write` call rather than repeating the `strlen` call.  And your
`read` and `write` calls here and elsewhere should really all be
error-checked (some are, some are not).

When writing the file to disk, I don't see a good reason for opening
the file buffered (`fopen` from stdio) but writing un-buffered
(`write`) - I would use `fwrite`.

A minor point is that the 32 used as the file-size buffer

```
char sz[32];
read(sockfd, sz, 32);
int fileSize = atoi(sz);
```

should really be a constant defined in a header shared between client
and server.  And I would use it just once:

```
char sz[SIZE_BUFFER_SIZE];
read(sockfd, sz, sizeof sz);  // use sizeof
int fileSize = atoi(sz);
```

---

In `serverFileTransfer` the `filename` parameter is not used.  I
would expect to see the check for the accepted socket being invalid
immediately after the `accept` call.  Also this socket is never closed
(not here and not in the `fileWrite` thread.

In `clientFileTransfer` the socket is not closed.

Comment: You have no reason to apologize. I appreciate your answer and it is really helpful. You said that you would use SIZE_BUFFER_SIZE only once, and then use sizeof operator. Why?

Comment: Just that the size of `sz` is guaranteed to be given by `sizeof sz`, whereas it is not guaranteed to be `SIZE_BUFFER_SIZE` unless you really did dimension `sz` with that constant. In this case the two expressions are adjacent and it is clear, but in general they are not and it is easy for the definition and use to drift apart. BTW, `SIZE_BUFFER_SIZE` was just the first constant name that came to mind - you can probably improve it :-)